# Autonomous navigation and avoiding obstacles

Tags: navigation, turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry I am new to ROS.

May I ask, is there any navigation stack (for Turtlebot) that allows the robot to reach the goal location (in a known map) and go round some new, small obstacles on-the-way (not shown in the map). Do I need to add some user code in an existing stack?

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51747/autonomous-navigation-and-avoiding-obstacles/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2014-08-06**:
Hi Chik, did you finish your project. I'm trying to do exactly same. can you help me? I have pioneer 3D-X mobile robot with odometer and laser. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Chik,

Have you checked out the [navigation stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation)?
There you have all the information needed to get your robot navigating autonomously in no time.

This stack includes path planners that will allow your robot to navigate a known map while avoiding unknown obstacles.

For the case of turtlebot you can check out [turtlebot_navigation stack](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/)

Have fun!

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-01-08**:
I watched the movie in navigation stack. This is cool! Does Turtlebot give the same navigation performance as PR2 ?

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2013-01-09**:
Well, PR2 is far more complex than Turtlebot and equipped with more sensors for navigation than just a Kinect. Which makes PR2 navigation "better" than turtlebot's, but the performance of turtlebot is good enough for hobbyists and even research

**Comment by [salma](https://answers.ros.org/users/3271/salma/) on 2013-03-21**:
@Martin Peris

i want my turtlebot search for an object in the room without determine the place of the goal in rviz ,,, I mean that Can i ask turtlebot for a Juice and it can autonomusly search the room by my 2D map  to get the Juice ?
the goal here is detect the Juice Not an exact place